# How do i use javascript to manipulate empty divs?

Tags: javascript, html

So this is what i want to do. if my div doesn't contain anything a js file will write "no links check in the future."
my html file:

```html
<div id="games" load="checknull(this)"></div>
```

my js file:

```js
function checknull(id) {
    gamelist = document.getElementById(id);
    if (gamelist.innerHTML == null) {
        gamelist.innerHTML = "No links check in the future"
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work! I've linked the external js file correctly its name and the tag!

Comment: The innerHTML of an empty element is likely `""` not `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>empty div</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="games"></div>

    <script>
      gameList = document.getElementById("games");

      window.onload = function () {
        if (!gameList.innerHTML) {
          return (gameList.innerText = "No links check in the future");
        }
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `load` event on a `div`.

You can achieve the result you're looking for with the `onload` event of either `body` or `window` depending on the rest of your code:

```
<body onload="checknull(this)">

</body>
```

Comment: Upvoting as this is most likely the root cause of the issue.  However, it is worth noting that there are other issues with this code that could be yielding strange/unexpected behavior, including non-idiomatic usage of weak equality checking and undeclared variable usage.

Answer (score 1):

There is two things that will not work. load handle doesn't exist on div so you could use [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) and your condition "gamelist.innerHTML == null" will always be false you should use gamelist.innerHTML == "".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, divs don't have event "load", so if you want to wait until the DOM is loaded use document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback) instead.
Also, innerHTML and innerText either are strings, not null.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  gamelist = document.getElementById("games");
  if (!gamelist.innerHTML) {
    gamelist.innerHTML = "No links check in the future"
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="games" load="checknull(this)"></div>
```

Comment: if you want to get help  you should be more clear describing problems. What do you mean 'it still does not work' - any errors, alerts etc? Have you tried to run the snippet?